# Making a calculator in android. The app shows up on the emulator with no errors but when I press the calculate button it crashes

Tags: java, android, emulation, calculator

I'm new to this and I'm trying to follow some code from another answer. I have three text fields to enter the numbers that are used for the calculation and a button below that is supposed to change some text below it to the answer. There are no errors shown when I run the app but when I press the button the app crashes and I get error messages in the log. This is the code:

```
public class CalculatorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    class NewActivity extends CalculatorActivity {
        //Declare textviews as fields, so they can be accessed throughout the activity.
        EditText editTextSubsPrevious;
        EditText editTextSubsNow;
        EditText editTextDays;
        TextView calcText;
        Button calcButton;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);

            //Bind the EditText views

            editTextSubsPrevious = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubsPrevious);
            editTextSubsNow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSubsNow);
            editTextDays = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDays);

            calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);{
                View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //When the button is clicked, call the calculate method.
                        calculate();
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        public void calculate(){
            //get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
            Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(editTextSubsPrevious.getText().toString());
            Double value2 = Double.parseDouble(editTextSubsNow.getText().toString());
            Double value3 = Double.parseDouble(editTextDays.getText().toString());
            //do the calculation
            Double difference = (value2 - value1) / 7;
            Double percent = (difference / 325);
            Double amount;
            amount = value2 * Math.pow(1 + percent, value3);
            calcText.setText(amount.toString());

        }

    }
}
```

}

Here is the error message:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pausetheapp.futurefollowerandsubscribercalculator, PID: 3420
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method sendMessage(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'calcButton'
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:325)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.pausetheapp.futurefollowerandsubscribercalculator.CalculatorActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_calculator">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/textViewTitle"
    android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextSubsPrevious"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="@string/previousSubsTextField"
    android:width="300dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextSubsNow"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSubsPrevious"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:width="300dp"
    android:hint="@string/currentSubsTextField" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editTextDays"
    android:hint="@string/daysTextField"
    android:width="300dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSubsNow"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextSubsNow"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextSubsNow" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/accuracyText"
    android:id="@+id/textViewAccuracy"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextDays"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextDays"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextDays"
    android:textSize="10dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/calculateButton"
    android:id="@+id/calcButton"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewAccuracy"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="@string/calcDays"
    android:id="@+id/calcText"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/calcButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

I just added this line to the java file.

```
calcText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calcText);
```

Comment: Actually, I just corrected the error but the button still isn't working.

Comment: It looks like that you are not creating the calcText in your code.. so if you will try to call setText on calcText (which is null because i don't see where you created it) the app will crash..

Comment: Could you please share your layout file as well?

Comment: Your class's blocks are messed up ! Please notice that you are defining a sub-class inside the method onCreate. I think you miss typed the code into the SO question field. If this is really your code, try to declare your NewActivity class outside of a method implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilites of error

1> You have not defined `calcText`

```
 calcText.setText(amount.toString());
```

2> Or May be

```
 Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(editTextSubsPrevious.getText().toString());
        Double value2 = Double.parseDouble(editTextSubsNow.getText().toString());
        Double value3 = Double.parseDouble(editTextDays.getText().toString());

editTextSubsPrevious,`editTextSubsNow`,`editTextDays` => does not contain numbers so that it can be parsed to `Doubles`
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have following attribute in your layout XML file:

```
 android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

Then, when you click, android search for method `sendMessage(View view)` and it does not find (because you did not implemented)

> Could not find method sendMessage(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'calcButton'

So, since your are setting a `onClickListener` at runtime, I think you can delete `android:onClick="sendMessage"` from layout file.

Also, line below should be fixed as follows:

```
calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);
calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //When the button is clicked, call the calculate method.
        calculate();
    }
});
```

Comment: I added the calcText to the java and I got rid of the "sendMessage" in the xml file. Unfortunately, it's still not working when I press the calculate button. Nothing changes.

Comment: Ok.. I fould several other errors.. For example, you created one activity inside another one.. I'll simulate your code here and return with updates.

Comment: @PauseTheCat Could you please share also activity_calculator to prepare proper fix to your code?

Answer (score 0):

In your layout most probably you have assigned sendMessage() method to handle onClick event and have not created any such method in activity.

check for `android:onClick="sendMessage"` in your layout.

Either create a method sendMessage(View view) and write your code there or remove it and use your calcBtn.setOnClickListner(View.OnClickListner Object).

Answer (score 0):

If your app crashes in response to a button click it could be due to the following:

1. The function you registered for the onClick attribute of the button
   in the layout .xml file does not exist in the activity. You can make sure the function name in the onClick attribute matches the function name you mean to call in your activity.
2. Something in the onClick function causes an Exception. If this is the case you can use the debugger by setting a breakpoint inside
   that function and inspecting your code and values while you step
   through the program. [Debug Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

if u r using this

```
    calcButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);{
                    View.OnClickListener onClickListener =         new Button.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                           //When the button is clicked, call the calculate method.
                            calculate();
                        }
                    };
                }
```

u should use

```
    android:onClick="onClick"
```

else u need to  use

```
                    calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                     public void onClick(View v) {
                        //When the button is clicked, call the      calculate method.
                                 calculate();
                                }

      });
```